# Overlapping views with one VISIBILITY set to GONE causes other views to disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I have a RelativeLayout containing 3 ImageViews (A, B and C). When one of these is clicked, the other two will fade out, and the clicked image will slide over to the position that A is in. If the clicked image is A, then the other two will just fade out. After the image has finished it's sliding animation, the other images visibility properties are set to GONE.

When the clicked image is A, this works exactly as I would expect it to. But when the clicked image is B or C (which is now occupying the same space as A), setting the visibility of A to GONE causes the clicked image to also disappear (as in, I can't see it).

If I set the visibility of the non-clicked images to INVISIBLE instead of GONE, then there's no problem. I should also mention that if A is clicked, there's no problem either.

So, the problem seems to be if two views overlap, where one of the view's visibility is set to VISIBLE and the other's is set to GONE, then you won't be able t ()o see either of them. Why does this happen? Is the space taken up by the view with visiblility GONE essentially unusable screen space until it's marked VISIBLE again? I'm sure I could just remove the views instead of setting them to GONE, but I'd prefer not to. I'll be reactivating them not long after I want them to disappear.

**EDIT:**
I've changed the animation code to use ObjectAnimator, in case the problem was that the view was not actually translating properly. It didn't fix the problem, the translated view is still disappearing after I set the visibility of the other views to GONE. The problem actually persists even if I remove the other views, instead of setting their visibility to GONE (e.g. using rootLayout.removeView(view)).

Here's the layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,PxUsage">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_A"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="image_spacing"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image_B"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/image_spacing"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_A"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image_C"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/image_spacing"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_B"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

...and some code:

```
image.animate()
    .translationXBy(slideDistance)
    .setDuration(slideDuration)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            for (int i=0; i<rootLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (i == selectedImage) continue;
                rootLayout.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I haven't found a solution to this yet, but as a workaround, I'm just setting the visibility of the unclicked views to INVISIBLE. It's not ideal, but it does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `android:layout_toRightOf` layout attributes. When the target view is gone, the layout rule doesn't really know where to place the view.

You can try with [`layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignWithParentIfMissing) which makes the view align to the parent relative layout if another layout rule's target view is missing.

Or if it works the way you want with `INVISIBLE`, you can also go with that.

Comment: I added alignWithParentIfMissing="true" to each image, but it didn't make a difference (it seemed like good logic though). I really prefer not to have to go with INVISIBLE, because once the sliding animation is complete, I want populate the RelativeLayout with some other views, and I don't want the invisible views interfering or causing any problems. Plus, they would be unnecessarily contributing to the layout.